# Where are joins constructed in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am having an issue with Rails and I need to find the point where the join part of the query is being built. The problem is, in short, that different versions of Rails use a different alias for the joined table (possibly a bug).

I have two models using single inheritance table and I need to do a query on this table referencing a field from a third model. I am interested in finding how the `"clients"."party_id"` (the table name) part of the following query is being constructed:

```
SELECT "clients".* 
FROM "clients" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "clients" "master_clients_clients" ON "master_clients_clients"."id" = "clients"."master_client_id" AND "master_clients_clients"."type" IN ('MasterClient') 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "parties" ON "parties"."id" = "clients"."party_id" 
WHERE ("parties"."name" LIKE '%arty%')
```

I really had a hard time finding this point and until now I haven't succeeded. So, would appreciate any tip in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

From [File](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/00f55516509770f58f9ce462d45afb80d8f649ca/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb#L74-L94):

`ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods::JoinDependency` breaks an association into `base`, `associations` and `joins`, which are further used to construct the Query, as has been commented in this file:

> ```
>   # base is the base class on which operation is taking place.
>   # associations is the list of associations which are joined using hash, symbol or array.
>   # joins is the list of all string join commands and arel nodes.
>   #
>   #  Example :
>   #
>   #  class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
>   #    has_many :appointments
>   #    has_many :patients, through: :appointments
>   #  end
>   #
>   #  If I execute `@physician.patients.to_a` then
>   #    base # => Physician
>   #    associations # => []
>   #    joins # =>  [#<Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin: ...]
>   #
>   #  However if I execute `Physician.joins(:appointments).to_a` then
>   #    base # => Physician
>   #    associations # => [:appointments]
>   #    joins # =>  []
>   #
> ```

---

`ActiveRecord` uses conventions over configurations. When You do

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :clients
end
```

It assumes, that you will have a table name `clients` which will `party_id` field as a foreign key for table `parties`.

You can read more about these conventions [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions).

Comment: I know, I need to step into these conventions and find how are they defined.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: If you are looinng to overwrite these conventions, You can head over to [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions)

Comment: It is single table inheritance, I don't need a different table name. I need to hook into the place where a table name is used to build the join. And I need to see which alias is used for this operation.

Comment: @AndreiHorak: I believe this is happening [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/00f55516509770f58f9ce462d45afb80d8f649ca/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb)

Comment: That's where I ended in my long search, but still couldn't find the relevant piece of code...

Comment: just lol here `has_many :client` should be  `has_many :clients` .

Comment: @saurabh regarding your update, that happens when your query specifically contains `joins` or refer to association fields...I didn't manage to check where this gets done for single table inheritance models...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at here : `activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb` and line `L428`.   [More...](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0399b71dab8b270b4e40b2aff99194a8b8f2596c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L428)

Comment: I think execution gets here only when you explicitly do a query using `.joins`.

Comment: Follow that method, maybe it leads you to your answer. best luck. Following this question.